# How to find an open set $W$ around $1\in S^1$ so that $\Delta\subset \{(x, wx)\mid x\in S^1, w\in W\} \subset U$ for an open $U$?

Tags: general-topology

This is a question on a practice topology qual. Here is the full wording:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $S^1\times S^1$ containing $\Delta = \{(x, x)\mid x\in S^1\}$.
Show that there exists an open $W\subset S^1$ containing $1\in S^1$ so that $V = \{(x, wx) \mid x\in S^1, w\in W\}$ is an open set such that $\Delta \subset V \subset U$.

Here is what I have so far:

Define $U' = \{(x, \frac{y}{x} \mid (x, y)\in U\}$.
Since $(x, x)\in U$ for all $x\in S^1$, we have $(x, 1)\in U'$ for all $x\in S^1$.
That is, $S^1\times \{1\}\subset U'$.
Since $S^1$ is compact, by the [the tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma), $U'$ contains some tube $S^1\times W$ about $S^1\times \{1\}$, that is, $S^1\times \{1\}\subset S^1\times W \subset U'$ for some open $W$ in $S^1$ containing $1$.

Now let $x\in S^1$ and $w\in W$.
Then $(x, w)\in U'$, so $w = \frac{y}{x}$ for some $y$ such that $(x, y)\in U$.
In particular, $(x, xw) = (x, y)\in U$.
Thus, $V\subset U$.
Since $1\in W$, we have $(x, x)\in V$ for all $x\in S^1$, so $\Delta\subset V$.

I'm pretty sure that I'm done with the main portion of the proof, however, I'm how to show that $V$ is actually open, even though intuitively it seems pretty obvious. How might I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The map $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$ is quite useful in this question: $V$ is the image of $S^1\times W$ under it. Also, you didn't  show that $U'$ is open in order to use the tube lemma.

Alternative solution: choose $\epsilon$ such that if $d((x,y),\Delta)<\epsilon$ (say the supremum metric) then $(x,y)\in U$. Use uniform continuity of the map $(x,y)\mapsto(x,xy)$ with this $\epsilon$, so if $w$ is sufficiently close to $1$, then $(x,xw)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $(x,x)$ for all $x$, and thus it is in $U$.